# POODLE - Monitor clients denied by disabling SSLv3

Tags: apache-http-server, logging, vulnerabilities

Is it possible via a log or something to view clients rejected by disabling SSLv3? I see the page comes up as "cannot be displayed" but I cannot find my request in any apache logs. It seems the request is logged somewhere if Apache is refusing it. The server that is denying requests is a proxy.

Basically I want make sure the impact of disabling SSLv3 is as negligible as it has been said to be.

Answer (score -1):

Try enabling logging for mod_ssl. It's off by default. Unfortunately, you didn't say what version of mod_ssl you're using.

Newer versions of mod_ssl use the ErrorLog and LogLevel directives. Add the following to ssl.conf:

```
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log
LogLevel warn
```

You can also use a CustomLog format in apache:

```
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ssl_engine.log \ "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
```

Older versions of mod_ssl use SSLLog and SSLLogLevel as described below:

**SSLLog**

- Name:  SSLLog
- Description:  Where to write the dedicated SSL engine logfile
- Syntax:  SSLLog filename
- Default:  None
- Context:  server config, virtual host
- Override:  Not applicable
- Status:  Extension
- Module:  mod_ssl
- Compatibility:  mod_ssl 2.1

This directive sets the name of the dedicated SSL protocol engine logfile. Error type messages are additionally duplicated to the general Apache error log file (directive ErrorLog). Put this somewhere where it cannot be used for symlink attacks on a real server (i.e. somewhere where only root can write). If the filename does not begin with a slash ('/') then it is assumed to be relative to the Server Root. If filename begins with a bar ('|') then the following string is assumed to be a path to an executable program to which a reliable pipe can be established. The directive should occur only once per virtual server config.

**Example:**

```
SSLLog /usr/local/apache/logs/ssl_engine_log
```

Sources:

- http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.8/ssl_reference.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html

Comment: We do have mod_ssl enabled, but I know it's a bear to sift through the logging. When I get a chance I will take a look.

Comment: I imagine you have mod_ssl enabled already - to be clear, you need to enable logging for mod_ssl. Errors will go to the apache error log unless you specify a different location. TLS/SSL and Ciphers used will be appended to apache access logs if you use the custom log format variables: %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x and %{SSL_CIPHER}x